# Calculating the moments of the N^th prime count

Tags: statistics, reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

The prime number theorem gives a rather famous result that

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\pi(n)}{\text{Li}(n)} \rightarrow 1 $$

So that in some sense $\text{Li}(n)$ could be interpreted as the expected value of $\pi(n)$. From there conjectures such as riemann hypothesis hope to bound

$$ | \pi(n) - \text{Li}(n)| \le \frac{1}{8\pi} \sqrt{n} \log(n) $$

But instead of worst case bounds, we may be tempted instead to ask the question what is a function $\theta(n)$ such that

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|\pi(n) - \text{Li}(n)|}{\theta(n) } \ \rightarrow 1 $$

I.E. what is the "standard deviation" of the prime counting function from its expected value.

And more generally if we define $E[F]$ as function $\psi(n)$ such that $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{F(n)}{\psi(n)} \rightarrow 1 $$

then $\text{Li(n)} = E[\pi(n)]$ and $\theta(n) = \sqrt{E[\pi(n)]^2 - E[\pi(n^2)]}$. So one could instead repose these questions about statistics as looking for functions $\Gamma_k$ such that

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\pi(n^k)}{\Gamma_k(n)} \rightarrow \infty $$

Has anyone tabulated $\Gamma_k(n)$?

Comment: I doubt $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|\pi(n) - \text{Li}(n)|}{\theta(n) } \ \rightarrow 1$ is quite what you mean

Comment: $\pi(x) - \text{Li}(x)$ has a complicated oscillating behavior ([plot it](http://urlz.fr/61V8)!) given by [the non-trivial zeros of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch) $\zeta(s)$. There is no simple function $\theta$ such that $\pi(x) - \text{Li}(x) \sim \theta(x)$, unless the RH is false and there is an isolated zero $\zeta(\rho) = 0, \frac{\zeta(s)}{s-\rho} \ne 0$ for $\Re(s) \ge \Re(\rho)-\epsilon$.

Comment: @reuns I see, so RH is basically asking for how to bound that freaky graph, and presumably if the bound is sufficiently tight, that would give rise to the $\theta$ I'm interested in?